# Test Program in Windows Environment on OS X

Tags: java, windows, macos, jfilechooser, look-and-feel

I have noticed some strange behavior, which actually results from differences in the layout of a JFileChooser when using Mac OS X or Windows.

On my Mac the window looks like this:

[image: OS X Dialog]

Whereas on Windows it looks like the following:

[image: Windows Dialog]

My question is: is there any chance that I can simulate the Windows look on my Mac? Because I do not have a Windows computer, so I cannot test any changes, but always have to wait for somebody else to test it, which, of course, is painfully slow as it is only a matter of parameterization.

```
public DelimiterFileChooser(String[] comboChoices) {
    comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
    comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(comboChoices));
    JPanel comboPanel = null;
    if (os.indexOf("mac") >= 0 || os.indexOf("nix") >= 0 || os.indexOf("nux") >= 0 || os.indexOf("aix") > 0) {
        comboPanel = (JPanel) this.getComponent(4);
        comboPanel = (JPanel) comboPanel.getComponent(2);
    } else {
        comboPanel = (JPanel) this.getComponent(3);
        comboPanel = (JPanel) comboPanel.getComponent(3);
    }
    Component c1 = comboPanel.getComponent(0);
    Component c2 = comboPanel.getComponent(1);
    comboPanel.removeAll();
    comboPanel.add(getPanel(new JLabel("Use delimiter for .csv:"), comboBox));
    comboPanel.add(c1);
    comboPanel.add(c2);
}
```

For those who are interested, here is my code. I have found the Windows part in [another Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309517/custom-jfilechooser-how-to-add-jcombobox-into-the-jfilechooser) and initially wondered why it did not work on my Mac. Now that I know that obviously the dialogs are differently build on different OS systems, I stopped wondering, yet the suggested solution in the thread does not do the trick for me.

Comment: Why not run a virtual windows machine on your Mac? Using Parallels, VMWare or the free VirtualBox? Just changing the L&F, even if the L&F is authentic, would still be giving you Mac paths (you won't be able to see or choose things like `C:`, `D:` etc. which do not exist on a Mac).

Comment: Turned out my code works on a virtual machine as it is supposed to be. It looks exactly like it should in the last link I posted. I'll get the feedback of the person I asked whether it also works for them now. If it doesn't there is probably nothing I can do about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to run Windows on your OS-X machine, try [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), [VmWare Fusion](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion) or [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/). It makes running (multiple) Windows version easy on a Mac. To test the software.